# How create an input box having a + and - button in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view, ionic-popup

How I can create an input box having a + and - button. Clicking upon which user can change the quantity of product selected, like this screen:

[image: input box having a + and - button]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a quickly thrown together example for Ionic 2. If you are using Ionic 1 you should be able to adapt it pretty easily.

You just need a couple controller/class functions to increment and decrement, then call those on tap from the buttons. This example covers just one button, so something like this wrapped in an `ngFor` or a `<ion-list>`

page.ts:

```
private currentNumber = 0;
constructor () { }

private increment () {
  this.currentNumber++;
}

private decrement () {
  this.currentNumber--;
}
```

page.html:

```
<ion-icon name="remove-circle" (click)="decrement()">
{{currentNumber}}
<ion-icon name="add-circle" (click)="increment()">
```

Comment: And who not permit value < 0?

Comment: How I can put a Sub-Total in the Header?

Comment: To prevent the value from gong below zero:

private decrement () {
  if (this.currentNumber > 0) {
    this.currentNumber--;
  }
}

Comment: For subtotal, just create a function to add them, set the result to a var like this.subtotal, then show that in the template with {{subtotal}}

Comment: Thank you, Great!

Comment: If you wrap this in a list, all the values will be increased or decresed with this answer. It should decrease or increase only the current item.

Answer (score 5):

As for ionic v.1 at your template you could have something like:

```
<div class="flex_row">
  <button class="button icon ion-minus-circled red" ng-click="sub(item)">
  <p> {{item.quantity}} </p>
  <button class="button icon ion-plus-circled green" ng-click="add(item)">
</div>
```

At your css

```
    .red:before {
    color: red;
    }

    .green:before {
    color: green;
    }

    .flex_row {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row; 
    flex-direction: row;
    }
```

And in your controller

```
$scope.sub = function(i) {
  i.quantity--;
}

$scope.add = function(i) {
  i.quantity++;
}
```